# Reposicionar gotoxy(x, y) com C

Tags: c

Estou utilizando a função gotoxy, para poder escrever em determinada coordenada:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h> 

void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){x-1,y-1});
}

main(){
    #chamando a função
    gotoxy(40, 20);
    printf("testando");
}
```

A função posiciona e escreve normalmente na coordenada, mas ao utilizar outro `printf("\ntestando")`, o texto é escrito a partir da linha escolhida na função, no caso do exemplo, na linha 21.

- Existe alguma forma de retornar para a linha que estava inicialmente, quando a função foi chamada?
- Quando se utiliza uma função de reposicionamento em coordenada, perde-se o controle de escrita do programa?